# In trouble with the Play Games tools

Tags: javascript, android, google-play-services

I would like to know if someone actually manage to make the play games tools to work. Hide-o-matic, reset-o-matic and score-o-matic. I'm a Android develloper and this is all about Javascript and HTML. If someone who is experimented with both android devellopement and web devellopment could help that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have used these tools and it is quite easy. Your problem is most likely that you are not running them through a web server, and this is a requirement. Download WAMP or XAMP (or similar) and run access the tools that way.

Comment: If you have a particular problem with using them, please update your question to specify what that is. Right now you are not asking much in terms of specifics.

Comment: I hosted the files on the internet ... I believe I don't need the download you provided to me in that case, right ?

Comment: In fact, to be more specific, as there is no error message I can't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Hosting it online should work fine. As long as you followed the instructions (`README.md` in each of the tools' folders) and made the required changes to the files before uploading them. You should also be logged into your G+ account before accessing the page.

Comment: The Javascript is Ok I believe. But in the HTML I have to put a client, I don't where to put it and don't know exactly what to put.

Comment: The value you need can be generated by creating a `web` linked app in the **Developer Console**. Once you've set it up you need to replace the `CLIENT_ID` in the HTML file with the `OAuth2 Client ID` generated in the developer console.

Comment: I also have to write the app id in the *.js file.It looks like it's exactly what I did... Is there a way to know where the error is coming from ?

Comment: Have a look at the javascript logging in the browser or use a javascript debugger. Note that if you have everything configured correctly, then you will see a popup when loading the page while you're signed into your google account. If all else fails you could try hosting it on your own machine using one of the web servers I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: I believe I did everything correctly. I'll try hosting it in localhost and use WaMp. I'll let you know if it worked or not

Comment: Do you know how I can delete an associated application ?

Comment: To delete an associated app, select it (i.e. open it's details page) and scroll to the bottom - there is a button labeled **Remove this app**. :)

Comment: I can't find this button... Where is it supposed to be ? I think I looked for it everywhere...

Comment: Under the AUTORISATION section I guess ?

Comment: It's in the Developer Console, where you add linked apps. It shows a list of linked apps.  Click the one you want to remove.

Comment: Then the button is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm definetely crazy. There is no button. I can screen it if you want

Comment: Here is the page I'm seeing : http://bit.ly/1nwvhXQ

Comment: And I can't get Wamp server to work. I'm not a web develloper, I don't understand any php stuff

Comment: Your screenshot is not there (resource not found). It is there for me on each linked app. I don't work for Google so I can't really tell you why yours is not showing. As for Wamp server, its really easy (you don't have to be a web developer)...just google for a tutorial on setting it up.

Comment: OK, I finally manage to delete the Web linked app (I deleted the game from the console and created it back). What am I supposed to write in the field "Launch URL" ? Something like : "http://localhost/reset-o-matic/achievement.html" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it was pretty simple indeed, 
Launch URL :

```
"http://localhost/"
```

Then I let the default URL and the client id generated fine.

I think something was wrong with my online host. 
Thanks for your help anyway